# Accessing FILESTREAM from an SQL CLR assembly

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, filestream, sqlclr

I'm trying to stream FILESTREAM data from an unsafe SQL CLR assembly.

The connection string is

```
Data Source=LAPTOP2\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False
```

When creating a new `SqlFileStream` (inside a `SqlTransaction`, of course), I'm getting:

> *The request is not supported*

at `OpenSqlFilestream`.

So I decided to try native [`OpenSqlFilestream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933972.aspx), but then I'm getting an invalid handle (-1) while `GetLastWin32Error` returns that same:

> *The request is not supported (`ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`)*.

I have also tried `SqlContext.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate()` with no apparent effect.

I couldn't find any documentation referencing this restriction. Is it really unsupported? If it is unsupported, is there a good reason? Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: I am encountering the same issue on SQL Server 2017 + Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

For access external resources, You need to set trustworthy on to database if you are using the external_access or unsafe permissions for assemblies because otherwise SQL server literally won't trust your code and won't let it go outside of the instance.
For file accessing (reading), i used

```
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FilePath, Encoding.Default))
            {

                string line;
                string allLine = "";

                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    allLine += line;

                }

            }
```

And for file write use

```
FileStream aFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(aFile, Encoding.Default);

        sw.Write(FilecontentsTOWrite);
        sw.Close();
        aFile.Close();
```

Comment: I'm already "unsafe", your answer is not related to FILESTREAM.